# Java CSVReader skips rows & how to transform csv

Tags: java, eclipse, csv, reader

I have been researching all day. And it doesn't matter how I code, the result is not what I want it to be.

First things first, I am working with Big Data, therefore, I do not think it is efficient to keep copy and pasting row entries.
I'm reading a CSV file, and it is working, it is cutting out everything I tell it to cut out. Everything is fine so far. Now, the only thing that is going wrong, is the fact that (my opinion) Eclipse (Java) cuts out headers/columnnames from the csv file. How to fix this problem?

```
package data;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;

import com.opencsv.CSVReader;

public class BelgiumParser {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //List<String> listBelgium;
    String fileName = "src\\data\\Belgium.csv";


    try{
        List<String> listBelgium = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName));

        //CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("src\\data\\Belgium.csv"), ',', '"', 1);

        for(String line : listBelgium){

            line = line.replace("\"" , "");
            line = line.replaceAll("T", " ");
            line = line.replaceAll("Z", "");                

            System.out.println(line);

    }}catch(Exception e){
        //System.out.println(e.getMessage());       
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

}

Also tried the while loop:

```
while(line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){...}
```

Yes I tried both bufferedReader and CSVReader. I might have even found the Python solution to this?

```
headers = next(reader, None)  # returns the headers or `None` if the input is empty

if headers:
    writer.writerow(headers)
```

Not my code, don't know how to link things. Main questions:

- How can I not only make sure that the header are printed (efficient way, I do not want copy/pasted piece of code)?
- But also, How can I make the Reader also Write the some of the headers vertically (Transforming)?

Update:
[image]

Containing hundreds of rows of data:
-No measurement equals null
-Measurement equals integer or doubles(?)
[image]

What should happen is:
- In the time, the T and Z have to go.
- T should be a space: " ", and Z just ""
- Column B and higher, row 1, should only contain the plantname itself.

Eventually, should be able to put this all in a MySQL DB, in a clear format, such that it can be implemented with a D3.js line chart, in a Java Server Faces (class?)

Comment: `How can I make the Reader also Write the some of the headers vertically (Transforming)?` What do you mean by this?

Comment: Imagine Excel: row 1 contains headers of the columns. I want to insert a new row (B), whereby everything gets moved one to the right. And then, from Column B row 1, I want to translate this and make it write in the newRowB

Answer (score 2):

If you are dealing with Big Data then I recommend you to get [univocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) as it is much faster than anything else. Then try not to load all rows in memory because it's an obvious problem, and stream them instead. Here's a simple example to get you started:

```
CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
settings.detectFormatAutomatically(); //you can configure the format manually if you prefer.
 parserSettings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true); //you want to get the headers from the input
settings.selectFields("a", "b", "c"); //select just the columns you need.

CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);

File input = Paths.get(fileName).toFile();
parser.beginParsing(input, "UTF-8");

String[] row;
while ((row = parser.parseNext()) != null) {
    //do your stuff here.

    //here are your headers
    String[] headers = parser.getContext().parsedHeaders();
}
```

Your second question, if I understood it correctly, is that you want to transpose the rows, i.e. have all data of a column associated with a header.

For that, use a `ColumnProcessor` (this loads all data in memory, I'll show you the alternative later):

```
ColumnProcessor columnProcessor = new ColumnProcessor();
parserSettings.setProcessor(columnProcessor);

CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(parserSettings);
parser.parse(input, "UTF-8"); //all rows are submitted to the processor created above.

//At the end of the process, you can get your data like this:
Map<String, List<String>> columnValues = new TreeMap<String, List<String>>(columnProcessor.getColumnValuesAsMapOfNames());
```

If you have too much data, you'll need to perform the transpose operation in batches. Use the `BatchedColumnProcessor` for that:

```
BatchedColumnProcessor columnProcessor = new BatchedColumnProcessor(20000 /*runs batches of 20000 rows each*/) {
    @Override
    public void batchProcessed(int rowsInThisBatch) {
        Map<Integer, List<String>> columnsByIndex = getColumnValuesAsMapOfIndexes();

       //process your batch here
    }
};
```

This should work perfectly. Hope it helps.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library, it's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license)

Comment: That looks so exciting! Will try it as soon as i get my hands on my laptop again! Will work on it today and let you know!

Comment: It seems to print certain things. Not in the format which i thought it should though. I believe it has to do with the parserSetting class. Shouldn't it be importable?

Comment: I'm not clear on what input you have and what you expect as the output. Can you update your question with a sample containing a couple of input rows, and the output you expect to get?

Comment: I hope it is understandable? If not, I am more than happy to explain in more detail

Comment: I finally got it to work! Ended up, not using your code, but I learned a lot from it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("src\\data\\Belgium.csv"), ',', '"', 1);
```

Last parameter in above code, you are asking the CSVReader to skip line1 while reading the file. Instead make use of the default(zero) so that it reads the Headers also.

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("src\\data\\Belgium.csv"), ',', '"', CSVReader.DEFAULT_SKIP_LINES);
```

Regarding the second question, you would have to write a custom logic by reading the lines into either Arrays or Lists which maintains the order, and handle writing with incremental index.

Comment: Aha! Thank you! Will try it! Hopefully will solve 1 question! Thank you so much!

Comment: Great. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Again, thank you for your suggestion! I tried it. However, IDE doesn't run at all when I do so.

Comment: Thank you for you time! I ended up using the first line. And it works :D

Answer (score 0):

The best way probably to do this is to essentially have it read each value of a column, and then store it into an array. Then write it into a new transformed CSV file that will print the entire array in one row in any order you want.

I can't really give you some psuedocode, because I am not completely familiar with any CSV reader Libraries, but it usually is easy to find one and use the Javadoc to implement it

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Am new to CSV reader Libraries too. Have been all over the internet and books. But not wiser... I like the idea, tried to do it. Didnt succeed

Answer (score 0):

Finally achieved what I was trying to do:

```
package code;

import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
import com.opencsv.CSVWriter;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class BelgiumParser {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String fileName = "src/data/Belgium.csv";

        try (CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(fileName), ',', '"', 1)) {
            String[] nextLine;

            while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {

                for (String line : nextLine) {

                    line = line.replaceAll("T", " ");
                    line = line.replaceAll("Z", "");
                    line = line.replaceAll("ActualGenerationPerUnit.mean", "");
                    line = line.replaceAll("Plantname:", "");
                    //Escaping curly braces is a must!
                    line = line.replaceAll("\\{", "");
                    line = line.replaceAll("\\}", "");
                    System.out.println(line);

                }


            }
        }
    }}
```

Still not efficient enough, but does the job..